# Unable to upgrade to Laravel v10 algolia/scout-extended 2.0 illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3

Tags: php, laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I am trying to upgrade from Laravel 9 ---> 10. I went through their upgrade guide, but when I try to run composer update I get an error message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires algolia/scout-extended 2.0 -> satisfiable by algolia/scout-extended[v2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.11.0 (conflict analysis result)
    ...
    - algolia/scout-extended v2.0.0 requires illuminate/support ^8.0|^9.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.9].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.9, v10.0.0, ..., v10.13.5], laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.13.5]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.13.5].
```

From my understanding, `algolia/scout-extended 2.0` requires php 7.3, but Laravel 10 requires php 8.1? So am I not able to use algolia/scout on Laravel 10?

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "algolia/scout-extended": "2.0",
        "authorizenet/authorizenet": ">=1.9.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.7",
        "cmixin/business-time": "^1.11",
        "google/recaptcha": "^1.3",
        "hubspot/api-client": "^9.4",
        "jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper": "^3.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.10"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Use [algolia v3](https://packagist.org/packages/algolia/scout-extended#v3.0.0)

Comment: Didn't notice they had a version change, that worked! Thank you!